# Which Game Center API should I use when supporting multiple versions of iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

On the following link, there has been mentioned two ways to report scores to Game Center on iOS:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW9

The first version seems to be for versions of iOS 7+:

> Listing 4-2  Reporting a score to Game Center (iOS 7)

```
- (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forLeaderboardID: (NSString*) identifier
{
    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier: identifier];
    scoreReporter.value = score;
    scoreReporter.context = 0;

    NSArray *scores = @[scoreReporter];
    [GKScore reportScores:scores withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    //Do something interesting here.
    }];
}
```

The second is for iOS 6:

> Listing 4-3  Reporting a score to Game Center (iOS 6)

```
- (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forLeaderboardID: (NSString*) category
{
    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category];
    scoreReporter.value = score;
    scoreReporter.context = 0;

    [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
// Do something interesting here.
    }];
}
```

My deployment target is iOS 6.0. So which API should I use ? The iOS 7 version ? Or should I call the API depending of the version of iOS on device like in the code below:

```
- (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forLeaderboardID: (NSString*) identifier
{

    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        // iOS 7
        GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier: identifier];
        scoreReporter.value = score;
        scoreReporter.context = 0;

        NSArray *scores = @[scoreReporter];
        [GKScore reportScores:scores withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            //Do something interesting here.
        }];
    }else{
        //iOS 6
        GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:identifier];
        scoreReporter.value = score;
        scoreReporter.context = 0;

        [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            // Do something interesting here.
        }];
    }
}
```

EDIT: The version for iOS 6, is deprecated on later versions of iOS.
EDIT: Also, if I am supporting both versions depending on the version of iOS, then what is the difference between identifier and category ? Are they both the same ?

Comment: Deprecated != gone. If you really need to support iOS 6 I'd say go with it.

Comment: Agree with @HAS. My advice would be to **not** have two separate code paths. If you need to support iOS6, use the deprecated API; it still works fine. Better advice: stop supporting iOS 6. :)

Comment: What is wrong with having two code paths ? Won't it be better since I am checking the OS version and using the correct path ?

Comment: It adds (unnecessary) complexity.